KMP cinterop swiftklib not resolved
I’m new to Kotlin Multiplatform for Android and iOS.
I’m trying to use a custom Swift Class I created in Kotlin Class. After doing some research, I found that it can be done using cinterop, and it’s easier with the io.github.ttypic.swiftklib plugin. The swift file is located in iosApp/KmpPlayer/player/CustomPlayer.swift. I’ve already integrated it into the shared Gradle file as follows:
kotlin {
 listOf(
 iosX64(),
 iosArm64(),
 iosSimulatorArm64()
 ).forEach {

        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
            isStatic = true
        }
    
        it.compilations {
            val main by getting {
                cinterops {
                    create("player")
                }
            }
        }
    
    }

}


swiftklib {
 create("player") {
  path = file("../iosApp/KmpPlayer/player")
  packageName("com.player")
 }
}

Player.swift

@objc public class Player: NSObject {

    @objc public func setSource(urlString: String) {
        print("playing \(urlString)")
    }

}

Versions:
AGP: 8.5.2
gradle: 8.9
Kotlin: 2.0.21
SwiftKlib: 0.6.4
Android Studio: Koala Feature Drop | 2024.1.2 Patch 1
Xcode: 16.1
The issue: The build succeeds, app can run, but when I try to import com.player in shared.iosMain, it is not resolved.
Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thank you.
